# How to execute Angular 2+ functions from console?

Tags: angular

My app will run encapsulated inside a cromium browser with chromiumfx.

chromiumfx are capable to execute any existing JS functions just like you operating a console.

I've this application...

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { GlobalService} from './global.service';
 import {Router} from "@angular/router";
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
 })
 export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private gs: GlobalService, private router: Router) {

   }
  tst() {
    console.log('hello');
   }
 }
```

I need to execute tst() from the console to simulat an action from cromiumfx. Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dev mode you can just write:

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance.tst()
```

where `$0` points to your component host element.

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/Tnrqia9o07gUyLE90Xim)**

[image]